# Access many different components added dynamically

Tags: angular, components

In my component i add different components dynamically using `ComponentResolver` and `ComponentFactory`, my question is if there is a way to access all off these like with `@ViewChildren`?

`@ViewChildren(AImageContentComponent)`   <--- could you pass an array into this?

```js
import {Component,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactory,ComponentResolver,ViewChildren,QueryList} from '@angular/core';

import {Child1} from './child1.component';
import {Child2} from './child2.component';
import {Child3} from './child3.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'authoring-phone',
    template: `
        <div (click)="loadContent()" class="phone">
              <div class="phone-screen"> 
                <div #target></div>
              </div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class ParentComponent{

@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;

@ViewChildren(????????)    <------
allComponents: QueryList<???????>;<--------


contentType;

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private _authoringService:AuthoringService) 
    {

    }

    addContent(type)
    {
        switch (type)
            {
            case 'child1' :
                this.contentType = Child1;
                this.addContentComponent();
                break;
            case 'child2' :
                this.contentType = Child2;
                this.addContentComponent();            
                break;
            case 'child3' :
                this.contentType = Child3;
                this.addContentComponent();            
                break;
            }
    }

    addContentComponent()
    {
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.contentType).then(
            (factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
            var cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
            var cmp = cmpRef.instance;                
            }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think there is something. You can maintain such a list yourself if you add components in your code. For example add them to an array of a shared service.